# I am using one notebook to another notebook in databrick -spark-scala

Tags: scala, azure, apache-spark, databricks

I have one notebook name "paths" and I want to use some of val declared in it, in another notebook, but I am getting error. I am using spark-scala

```
%run "/paths"
```

error

```
Notebook not found: paths. Notebooks can be specified via a relative path (./Notebook or ../folder/Notebook) or via an absolute path (/Abs/Path/to/Notebook). Make sure you are specifying the path correctly.
```

Comment: Where is your `paths` notebook stored? Right now, you're trying to reference it from the root folder.

Comment: I created folder in workspace and inside it is `paths` @DavidMakogon

Comment: So, if you have a folder, you either need to specify the exact path of the folder, or choose a relative path. You're not finding your notebook because you're trying to reference it from the root folder, not inside the containing folder.

Comment: Thanks a lot @DavidMakogon Its working

Answer (score 0):

Please use %run /Users/testuser/TESTParam

You can also pass Additional  paramters like

%run /Users/testuser/TESTParam $runtype = "Sequential" $configuration="xxx" $runnumber=1-10

Comment: Thank you @ jeevan madhur . Can you tell me, if I want to use any specific variable, how it can be configured

Answer (score 0):

You can run below code to get current notebook absolute path

```
dbutils.notebook.entry_point.getDbutils().notebook().getContext().notebookPath().get()
```

then you can use `%run <path>`

Comment: But will your suggestion not give the current notebook's path, and not the referenced notebook's path?